# DialogResult and show message on button click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms Form1 and Form2.

Inside Form1 I call Form2 and I want to intercept user button click choice. If user on Form2 clicked on Ok or Cancel button, so I try

```
var editForm = new Form2();
editForm.ShowDialog();
if (editForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("ok btn is pressed!");
      editForm.Dispose();
 }
 else
 {
      MessageBox.Show("cancel btn is pressed!");
      editForm.Dispose();
 }
```

on Form2 I have click events

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _Repository.Create(mydata);
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       Close();
  }
```

Display message is show only on Cancel button and not on Ok. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the reason it only works for cancel is because you are only handling `if DialogResult == DialogResult.OK`, meaning if the `DialogResult` is not `OK` it will just fall into the `else` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `dialog result` before closing.

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _Repository.Create(mydata);

     DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
     Close();
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your Form1 :

```
  using (Form2 editForm = new Form2())
            {
                editForm.ShowDialog();
                if (editForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ok btn is pressed!");
                    editForm.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("cancel btn is pressed!");
                    editForm.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

And on Form2 :

```
    private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Repository.Create(mydata);
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
```

Comment: Oups, it was already been answered. BTW, no need to call Close() when setting the value of DialogResult